# How to create a python class with a single use context

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

If we look at [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#single-use-reusable-and-reentrant-context-managers) it states:

> Most context managers are written in a way that means they can only be used effectively in a with statement once. These single use context managers must be created afresh each time they’re used - attempting to use them a second time will trigger an exception or otherwise not work correctly.
>
> This common limitation means that it is generally advisable to create context managers directly in the header of the with statement where they are used (as shown in all of the usage examples above).

Yet, [the example most commonly shared for creating context managers inside classes is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#using-a-context-manager-as-a-function-decorator):

```py
from contextlib import ContextDecorator
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class track_entry_and_exit(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        logging.info('Entering: %s', self.name)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, exc_tb):
        logging.info('Exiting: %s', self.name)
```

But, when I instantiate this class, I can pass it several times to a with statement:

```py
In [8]: test_context = track_entry_and_exit('test')

In [9]: with test_context:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
INFO:root:Entering: test
INFO:root:Exiting: test

In [10]: with test_context:
    ...:     pass
    ...: 
INFO:root:Entering: test
INFO:root:Exiting: test
```

How can I create a class that fails on the second call to the with statement?

Comment: You can have a flag `self._is_called` and check it in `__enter__` method and the raise an error accordingly.

Comment: I guess, but given the documentation saying that this is the most common case, I can't believe that there isn't a more pythonic way. I'm expecting there to be a decorator of some sort, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Is this really the most common case? Arguably the most common use of context managers is `with open(...) as variable:` and it doesn't make sense to use it in multiple `with` statements.

Comment: Adding the @contextmanager decorator to the __enter__ method doesn't make this a single-use context.

Comment: @AndrésMarafioti You mean you want a decorator so that you can apply to CMs and make them one-time-use?

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Specially if it was already a part of python. Something like `from contextlib import singleuse`

Comment: create a global variable, set that once it's been invoked. check it when it's next invoked and then raise an error. It will of course only persist for the life of the current invocation

Comment: Err..., being single use is not really a desired feature of context managers. It is just a side effect of the way they setup and clear their internal state, just think about the `open` example given by Barmar in its comment. The doc you are citing is a warning to context manager users, just saying that the conservative way of using a CM is to declare it in the with statement. But the context manager that you use here is stateless and **can** safely be re-used at will. You can certainly build tools to force a stateless CM to become single use, but I cannot imagine a real world use case for that

Comment: I have a real-world use case where I want to do that, which is why I asked. I will probably go for the `self._was_called` approach. It seems like the answer to my question is 'there is no standard way to enforce single use on context managers in python'

Comment: In the case of a [`ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) the docs explicitly say that the context manager should be reentrant (because otherwise the decorated function could be used only once).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
from functools import wraps


class MultipleCallToCM(Exception):
    pass


def single_use(cls):
    if not ("__enter__" in vars(cls) and "__exit__" in vars(cls)):
        raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a Context Manager.")

    org_new = cls.__new__
    @wraps(org_new)
    def new(clss, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = org_new(clss)
        instance._called = False
        return instance
    cls.__new__ = new

    org_enter = cls.__enter__
    @wraps(org_enter)
    def enter(self):
        if self._called:
            raise MultipleCallToCM("You can't call this CM twice!")
        self._called = True
        return org_enter(self)

    cls.__enter__ = enter
    return cls


@single_use
class CM:
    def __enter__(self):
        print("Enter to the CM")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        print("Exit from the CM")


with CM():
    print("Inside.")
print("-----------------------------------")
with CM():
    print("Inside.")
print("-----------------------------------")
cm = CM()
with cm:
    print("Inside.")
print("-----------------------------------")
with cm:
    print("Inside.")
```

output:

```
Enter to the CM
Inside.
Exit from the CM
-----------------------------------
Enter to the CM
Inside.
Exit from the CM
-----------------------------------
Enter to the CM
Inside.
Exit from the CM
-----------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 51, in <module>
    with cm:
  File "...", line 24, in enter
    raise MultipleCallToCM("You can't call this CM twice!")
__main__.MultipleCallToCM: You can't call this CM twice!
```

I used a class decorator for it so that you can apply it to other context manager classes. I dispatched the `__new__` method and give every instance a flag called `__called`, then change the original `__enter__` to my `enter` which checks to see if this object has used in a `with-statement` or not.

How robust is this? I don't know. Seems like it works, I hope it gave an idea at least.

Comment: this is nice. I'd avoid names like `.__called` though: a single underline is enough to indicate the attribute should not be fiddled by code outside of the code where it is is created. Two underlines not only pass an incorrect message (along "this is _even more private_", I guess?) - but might trigger Python name mangling features in way that one will introduce a hard to find bug at some point.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno Agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the simplest method is mentioned two paragraphs further down in the documentation you have cited:

> Context managers created using contextmanager() are also single use context managers, and will complain about the underlying generator failing to yield if an attempt is made to use them a second time

Here is the corresponding invocation for your example:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def track_entry_and_exit(name):
...    print('Entering', name)
...    yield
...    print('Exiting', name)
... 
>>> c = track_entry_and_exit('test')
>>> with c:
...    pass
... 
Entering test
Exiting test
>>> with c:
...    pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 115, in __enter__
    del self.args, self.kwds, self.func
AttributeError: args
```

It's even a class although it is written as a function:

```
>>> type(c)
<class 'contextlib._GeneratorContextManager'>
```

Comment: That works for a function but not for a class:
```python
from contextlib import contextmanager


class track_entry_and_exit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @contextmanager
    def __enter__(self):
        print(f"Entering: {self.name}")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, exc_tb):
        print("Exiting: {self.name}")


a = track_entry_and_exit("a")
with a as b:
    print("Inside with block: {b.name}")

with a as b:
    print("Inside with block: {b.name}")
```

Comment: The point of `contextlib.contextmanager` is that you *don't* have to create a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, it does it for you.

Comment: But I want a class that does a whole bunch of other things and just happens to be used in a context such that creation and destruction are somewhat controlled.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to consider iterable class instead of context manager, like this

```py
class Iterable:
    """Iterable that can be iterated only once."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.it = iter([self])

    def __iter__(self):
        # code to acquire resource
        print('enter')
        yield next(self.it)
        print('exit')
        # code to release resource

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.name})'
```

It can be iterated only one

```py
>>> it = Iterable('iterable')
>>> for item in it:
>>>     print('entered', item)
enter
entered Iterable(iterable)
exit
>>> for item in it:
>>>     print('entered', item)
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Context manager can be written in this manner:

```py
class Context:
    """Context manager that can be used only once."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.it = iter([self])

    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
        return next(self.it)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, exc_tb):
        print('exit')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.name})'
```

It works only once

```py
>>> ctx = Context('context')
>>> with ctx as c:
>>>     print('entered', c)
enter
entered Context(context)
exit
>>> with ctx as c:
>>>     print('entered', c)
enter
StopIteration:
```